# How to navigate using google map from user's location to a fixed point on HTML5 webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, geolocation

I am new to geolocation and I tried a lot of times to get my website to locate user's location, but still I don't know how to navigate from user's position to a fixed point on Google map, I am using the codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pink.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />

    <style>
        #map-page, #map-canvas { width: 100%; height: 300px; padding: 0; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery Mobile 程式碼/ch9/maps.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com.tw/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$( "#map-page" ).live( "pageinit", function() {

    var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.983587,120.22599);  // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support

    if ( navigator.geolocation ) {
        function success(pos) {

            // Location found, show map with these coordinates
            drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        }

        function fail(error) {
            console.log(error);
            drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // Failed to find location, show default map
        }

        // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});
    } else {
        drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map    
    }

    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
    }

    //設置起點  
function setstart(){  

    var latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
    var title="Your Location";
    //地图中心坐标
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);    

    if(!startpoint){  

    startpoint = new google.maps.Marker({  

        map:myMap,  

        position:latlng,  

        draggable: true  

    });}  



}  


//設置終點  
function setend(){  

    var newcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(22.981666,120.194301);

    if(!endpoint){  

    endpoint = new google.maps.Marker({  

        map:myMap,  

        position:newcenter,  

        draggable: true  

    });}  

}  

//路線導航  
function start2end(model){  

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();  

    directionsDisplay.setMap(myMap);  
    var startlatlng=startpoint.getPosition();  
    var endlatlng=endpoint.getPosition();  
    $("#jczbresult").show("slow");  
    $("#jczbresultmin").hide();  
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': startlatlng}, function(results, status) {  
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {  
            if (results[1]) {  
                $("#startdrive").html('起點:'+results[1].formatted_address);  
            }}});   
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': endlatlng}, function(results, status) {  
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {  
            if (results[1]) {  

                $("#enddrive").html('終點:'+results[1].formatted_address);  
            }}});   

    if(model=='WALKING'){  
        $("#jczbtitle").innerHTML="步行查詢結果";  
        directionsService.route({  

            origin: startlatlng,  

            destination: endlatlng,  

            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING  

            }, function(result, status){  

                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){  

                     directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);//標記地圖顯示路線  
                     showSteps(result);//右側面板顯示詳細路線信息  

                    }  

                });  

        }else{  
            $("#jczbtitle").innerHTML="駕車查詢結果";  
            directionsService.route({  

                origin: startlatlng,  

                destination: endlatlng,  

                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING  

                }, function(result, status){  

                    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){  

                         directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);  
                         showSteps(result);//右側面板顯示詳細路線信息  

                        }  

                    });  

            }  



}  
//顯示起點終點之間的詳細信息  
function showSteps(directionResult) {  
    $("#driveline").html('');  
    var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];  
    var v_html = '';  
    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {  
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
        v_html += '<div class="carSearchtr02" id="driver_step_'+i+'">'+(i+1)+'.'+myRoute.steps[i].instructions+',此段路程為:'+myRoute.steps[i].distance.value+'米</div>';  
        //myRoute.steps[i].instructions;  
    }  
    if(v_html != '')  
    {  
         v_html = '<div class="carSearchtr01">总里程：'+myRoute.distance.value+'米</div>'+v_html;  
         $("#driveline").html(v_html);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
            $("#driveline").html('很抱歉，沒有找到符合您要的條件，您可以試試下面的方法:<br>調整一下您輸入的搜索關鍵字');  
    }  

  }  

});


    </script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="map-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse"></a>
        <h1>Maps</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="map-canvas">
        <!-- map loads here... -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"  class="ui-navbar-custom" >
        <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar-custom">
        <ul>
          <li><a  href="index.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="custom">首頁</a></li>
          <li><a href="listview.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="custom" >營業項目</a></li>
          <li><a href="news.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="custom" >最新消息</a></li>
          <li><a href="photo.html" data-ajax="false" data-icon="custom" >案例分享</a></li>
          <li><a href="phone.html" data-ajax="false"  data-icon="custom">聯絡我們</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However it doesn't work, can anyone tell me what's the wrong,thx

by the way, I have a demo of the code on

http://appkon.com/demo/project2/maps.html

thx again

Answer (score 0):

You have a function there that should draw the route: `start2end()` , but you didn't call this function anywhere.

So you should start by calling the function, e.g. inside the success-callback of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

You will receive different errors then, but fixing the errors should guide you to the desired result.

Comment: I tried what you said by adding start2end(WALKING) to function success(pos),but it doesn't change anything T-T,any other ideas?

Comment: Of course it will not work, take a look at the console and fix the errors you are receiving.